# MySQL and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in MySQL database:

**items**

```
id | item_name
---+----------
 1 | item1
 2 | item2
 3 | item3
 4 | item4
```

**tags**

```
id | tag_name
---+---------
 1 | A
 2 | B
 3 | C
```

**items_tags**

```
id | items_id | tags_id
---+----------+-------
 1 |    1     |   1
 2 |    1     |   2
 3 |    1     |   3
 4 |    2     |   1
 5 |    2     |   3
 6 |    4     |   3
```

I can get all items and tags using this query:

```
SELECT items.item_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) AS item_tags
FROM items 
    LEFT JOIN items_tags ON items.id=items_tags.items_id
    LEFT JOIN tags ON items_tags.tags_id=tags.id
GROUP BY items.id;

output:

item_name | item_tags
----------+----------
  item1   | A, B, C
  item2   | A, C
  item3   | NULL
  item4   | C
```

**Q1: How to get all items with specific tag**

```
... where is A tag

output: 

item_name | item_tags
----------+----------
  item1   | A, B, C
  item2   | A, C
```

**Q2: How to get all items without specific tag**

```
... where is not B

output:

item_name | item_tags
----------+----------
  item2   | A, C
  item3   | NULL
  item4   | C
```

**Q3: Combinations**

```
... where is C and is not B 

output:

item_name | item_tags
----------+----------
  item2   | A, C
  item4   | C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `HAVING` clause.

For a specific tag, e.g. *with* 'C':

```
SELECT items.item_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) AS item_tags
FROM items 
    LEFT JOIN items_tags ON items.id=items_tags.items_id
    LEFT JOIN tags ON items_tags.tags_id=tags.id
GROUP BY items.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN tags.tag_name = 'C' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

**Output:**

```
item_name  item_tags
=====================
item1      A,B,C
item2      A,C
item4      C
```

for *not have*, e.g. *not with* 'B':

```
SELECT items.item_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) AS item_tags
FROM items 
    LEFT JOIN items_tags ON items.id=items_tags.items_id
    LEFT JOIN tags ON items_tags.tags_id=tags.id
GROUP BY items.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN  tags.tag_name = 'B' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

**Output:**

```
item_name  item_tags
=====================
item2      A,C
item3      NULL
item4      C
```

and combinations, e.g. *not* B *and* 'A':

```
SELECT items.item_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) AS item_tags
FROM items 
    LEFT JOIN items_tags ON items.id=items_tags.items_id
    LEFT JOIN tags ON items_tags.tags_id=tags.id
GROUP BY items.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN tags.tag_name = 'B' THEN 1 END) = 0 AND 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tags.tag_name = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

**Output:**

```
item_name item_tags
===================
item2     C,A
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesnt work for me - adding "HAVING COUNT(tags.tag_name = 'A') > 0;" returns also item4 (only C tag)